# be chinese fonts in Flutter iOS app set Japanese in MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, text, fonts, chinese-locale, textstyle

I have an issue that the text in the iOS app display in Chinese font. so I tried three patterns. But it doesn't work only in the build iOS app. In the iOS simulator, all patterns work. How can I reflect localization?

① set locales in supportedLocales.

```
return MaterialApp(
    　　localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('ja', 'JP'),
          const Locale('en', ''),
        ],
    .....
    );
```

②set textStyle in Text()

```
  static const BoldBlack20 = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 20,
    locale: Locale('ja', 'JP'),
  );
```

③set CFBundleLocalizations in iOS/Runner/info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>English</string>
        <string>ja</string>
    </array>
```

screenshot In iOS simulator（Japanese）
[image]

screenshot In iOS app(Chinese)
[image]

I'd like to display Japanese one.

This is an app setting screenshot.
① In the simulator
[image]

② In iPhone
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Chinese Locale

```
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh'), // generic Chinese 'zh'
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh', scriptCode: 'Hans'), // generic simplified Chinese 'zh_Hans'
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh', scriptCode: 'Hant'), // generic traditional Chinese 'zh_Hant'
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh', scriptCode: 'Hans', countryCode: 'CN'), // 'zh_Hans_CN'
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh', scriptCode: 'Hant', countryCode: 'TW'), // 'zh_Hant_TW'
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh', scriptCode: 'Hant', countryCode: 'HK'), // 'zh_Hant_HK'
```

For Japan Locale

```
locale: Locale('ja', '')
```

And updating the iOS app bundle

> 1. Open your project’s ios/Runner.xcworkspace Xcode file.
> 2. In the Project Navigator, open the Info.plist file under the Runner
>    project’s Runner folder.
> 3. Select the Information Property List item. Then select Add Item from
>    the Editor menu, and select Localizations from the pop-up menu.
> 4. Select and expand the newly-created Localizations item. For each
>    locale your application supports, add a new item and select the
>    locale you wish to add from the pop-up menu in the Value field. This
>    list should be consistent with the languages listed in the
>    supportedLocales parameter.
> 5. Once all supported locales have been added, save the file.

[More detail](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Comment: I set `const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'ja'),` in supportedLocales. It display Japanese fonts in the iOS simulator, but building iOS app, it display Chinese fonts.

Comment: Would you mind to check the simulator and device environment setting? what is default language?

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: I added screenshots of the simulator and device environment setting above. It is not solved yet.

Comment: Let's do some test. Could you add this `Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);` and `print(myLocale)` to track the locale in both simulator and device

Comment: In both iOS simulator and iPhone, show `ja_JP` .

Comment: In both debug and release mode, the app in iPhone always shows Japanese font, but after building and uploading an app to TestFlight, the app in iPhone shows Chinese font.

Comment: I guess it maybe preferred locales fail to match, and system use Locale.countryCode to set the locale. try `locale: Locale('ja', '')`, I updated my answer

Comment: I have never tried TestFlight to test application, but I did some searching and found that may the Testflight setting causing the issue. You can open Testflight management console and set the correct language/region.